# Ajax call from frontend not working with wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wp-admin

Call to Ajax not working from frontend in WordPress,All i want to the data from db based on id,this is what i have tried so far.

```
//Frontend view

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getDetails(<?=$index;?>)" >
        <?php echo $value ?>
    </a>

//Functions.php

function my_enqueue() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );
      wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
 }

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_posts', 'get_more_posts');

function get_more_posts(){
    // How to get id here to query for the database
    echo "Hello World";
    exit(); 
}

// Ajax scripts File
function getDetails(id)
{
jQuery.ajax({
    url: more_posts.ajax_url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        action: 'more_posts'
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});
}
```

I am getting this error

> reference error more_posts is not defined

Comment: action: 'more_posts'   - more_posts doesn't look like a valid URL. Change it to `/page/url/to/call`

Comment: You should define more_posts, like var more_posts = 'http://'

Comment: @Sakezzz he doesn't need the protocol or domain, just the absolute path

Comment: thank you,i got my ajax working now,there was path issue.
How can i get the id in get_more_posts() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Frontend view

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getDetails(<?=$index;?>)" >
        <?php echo $value ?>
    </a>

//Functions.php

function my_enqueue() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );
      wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
 }

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_posts', 'get_more_posts');

function get_more_posts(){
    // How to get id here to query for the database
    echo "Hello World";
    echo $_GET['id'];
    exit(); 
}

// Ajax scripts File
function getDetails(id)
{
var id = id;
jQuery.ajax({
    url:  url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        action: 'get_more_posts',
        id: id,
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});
}
```

This should work! You dont need absolute path or var with '`href`',  `url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url`, is enough as you already added admin-ajax.php with `wp_enqueue_script`.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mistake in

```
  url: more_posts.ajax_url
```

Because you localize script name is my_ajax_object

```
 wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

try this

```
 url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url
```